# "Get-OwaVirtualDirectory" very very slow when accessing CAS in different site

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, winrm, remoting

I have a CAS server in a different AD site, and every Exchange 2010 command runs quickly... except for the one that use IIS and Get-XXXVirtualDirectory.  In these cases it takes several minutes for the results to come back.

Is this normal?  Can I issue other commands in WinRM to see what the issue is?

My concern is that I forgot to configure something (or it's set wrong) and I'm timing out.  I'd rather fix the issue now before it surprises me later on

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing "wrong" here.  All the Get-XXXVirtualDirectory commands query both AD and the IIS config - which is what's slowing things down.

As per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2896472, you can use the *-ADPropertiesOnly* switch to prevent querying IIS (across remote sites).

Cheers!